# Expectancy of a RV

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

I have a question. I know that a RV $X$ has the hyperbolic secant distribution (with density function $f_X(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}$). I have a few questions about calculating the expectancy (mean value):
Is $\int^{\infty}_{0}f_{X}(x)dx=\mathbb{E}[X\space{1}_{\{x>0\}}]$? (where $1$ indicates the indicator function)
And why does the fact that $X$ and $-X$ has the same distribution imply that $2\mathbb{E}[X\space{1}_{\{x>0\}}]=\mathbb{E}[X\space{1}_{\{x>0\}}]+\mathbb{E}[-X\space{1}_{\{x<0\}}]=\mathbb{E}[|X|]$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, by definition
$$
\mathbb E(\phi(X)) = \int_{\mathbb R} f_X(t) \phi(t) dt.
$$
(This can be proven from the somehow more basic definition $\mathbb E(x) =\int x f_X(x)$.) So if $\phi(x) =x 1_{\mathbb R^+},$ then
$$
\mathbb E(\phi(X)) = \int_{\mathbb R} f_X(t) \phi(t) dt=\int_{\mathbb R^+} f_X(t)tdt.
$$

For the second question, let me add some details: since $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, we have
$$
\mathbb E(\phi(X)) = \mathbb E (\phi(-X)).
$$
Now, what is $\mathbb E (\phi(-X))?$ Well, $\phi(-X) = (-x)1_{\mathbb R^+}(-x) = -x1_{\mathbb R^-} (x)$, which is what you have in the question.

Answer (score 1):

- No, it should be $\int_0^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx = E[X 1_{X > 0}]$.
- If $X$ has the same distribution as $-X$, then $X1_{X > 0}$ has the same distribution as $(-X) 1_{(-X) > 0} = -X1_{X < 0}$, so $E[X1_{X>0}] = E[-X1_{X<0}]$
- In general for any real number $x$ we have $|x| = x 1_{x>0} + (-x)1_{x<0}$, so  $E[|X|] = E[X1_{X > 0} + (-X) 1_{X < 0}] = E[X 1_{X > 0}] + E[-X1_{X<0}]$